# How to make _t version of SFINAE struct exposing static member value?

Tags: c++, templates, struct, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I have that code that recognizes which *GL type* you need to use based on C++ types. I want to make a `_t` version of it (like `std::decay_t` or `std::enable_if_t`) but expose `int` constant value

```
template <typename T, typename = void> struct GLType {};

template <typename T>
struct GLType<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::remove_pointer_t<std::decay_t<T>>, float>>> {
   const static constexpr int type = GL_FLOAT;
};

template <typename T>
struct GLType<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::remove_pointer_t<std::decay_t<T>>, double>>> {
   const static constexpr int type = GL_DOUBLE;
};
```

My first try was

```
template <typename T>
using GLType_t = GLType<T>::type;
```

but that doesn't work. Is it even possible to return value instead of type in the same way?
In the end, I want something like

```
int a = GLType_t<float>;
// instead of
int a = GLType<float>::type; // which works fine btw
```

Comment: According to the POSIX standard, names ending with _t are reserved for the implementation, so if you are targeting a POSIX system (e.g., Linux), you should not end your types with _t.

Comment: @jesperjuhl thanks for the info, but anyway i changed it to _v

Answer (score 4):

You appear to be looking for [variable-templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) which allow you to do this:

```
template <typename T>
inline constexpr int GLType_t = GLType<T>::type;
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
int a = GLType_t<float>;
```

Also, I strongly suggest that you name the `int` member something like `value` instead of `type`. Names matter, and `type` is just the wrong name for a member that is not actually a type.

Comment: thanks, that's what i wanted. Yes, in that case `value` has much more sense than `type`

Comment: I might recommend `GLType` -> `GLTypeTag`, `GLTypeTag::type` -> `GLTypeTag::value`, and `GLType_t` -> `GLType_v`, with those last two conforming to the C++ conventions. (See `<type_traits>`.)

Comment: Since C++17, `inline constexpr int GLType_t = ...`.

Answer (score 2):

The [@cigien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63197040/how-to-make-t-version-of-sfinae-struct-exposing-static-member-value/63197137#63197137) provided the way to go with [variable template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template).

However, I would like to propose a less typing approach using [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)s [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if). The entire boiler-plate traits code will meltdown to simply, a template-function:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
constexpr auto GLTypeHelper() noexcept
{
   // assert is the T is not either float or double
   static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, float> || std::is_same_v<T, double>, " T should be float or double");
   
   if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>) 
      return GL_FLOAT;
   else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>) 
      return GL_DOUBLE;
};

// variable template for GLType_v
template <typename T>
inline constexpr int GLType_v = GLTypeHelper<T>(); // calls the `GLTypeHelper()`
```

You will use it like

```
constexpr int a = GLType_v<float>;
constexpr int b = GLType_v<double>;
```

and ofcourse, since `GL_FLOAT` and `GL_DOUBLE`  are values, not a types, change the `::type` -> `::value`, and `_t` -> `_v`!